# If $h:M\to M$ is a smooth homeomorphism with $h\sim id$, do we have $h^{-1}\sim id$?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

> **Theorem.** Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold, and $p,q\in M$ are different points. Then there exists a smooth homeomorphism $h:M\to M$ which is homotopic to the identity map, such that $h(p)=q$.

There is a small point in the proof that I can not understand. The book I'm reading is a Chinese book on Differential Topology. The author defines a relation on $M$: for $a,b\in M$, we say $a\sim b$ if and only if there exists a smooth homeomorphism $h:M\to M$ with $h\sim id$ (here $h\sim id$ means homotopy) such that $h(a)=b$. It is said by the author that $\sim$ is a equivalence relation on $M$, without proof. So I tried myself.

It is clear that $a\sim a$, taking $h=id$ is enough. I also know how to prove transitivity: if $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ then $a\sim c$. Indeed, if $h_1$ is the homeomorphism mapping $a$ to $b$ and $F_1(t,x):[0,1]\times M\to M$ is the homotopy with $F_1(0,x)=x$ and $F_1(1,x)=h_1(x)$; similarly we have $h_2$ and $F_2$, then $h:=h_2\circ h_1$ is the homeomorphism mapping $a$ to $c$ and $F(t,x)=F_2(t,F_1(t,x))$ is the homotopy connecting $id$ and $h$.

However, I don't know how to prove the symmetry of $\sim$, namely, $a\sim b$ implies $b\sim a$. If  $h$ is the homeomorphism mapping $a$ to $b$ and $F(t,x):[0,1]\times M\to M$ is the homotopy with $F(0,x)=x$ and $F(1,x)=h(x)$, then $h^{-1}$ is the homeomorphism mapping $b$ to $a$. But, we can not simply take the homotopy to be $F_t^{-1}$ because we don't know whether $F_t$ is homeomorphism or not. So, how to prove that $h^{-1}\sim id$?

I'm not good at geometric stuffs. If my question is silly, forgive me please. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F$ is a homotopy from $\mathrm{id}$ to $h$, the homotopy $\bar F$ given by $\bar F(t, x) = F(t, h^{-1}(x))$ goes from $h^{-1}$ to $\mathrm{id}$. Note that $\bar F$ is a composition of smooth functions and therefore smooth, and by definition
$$
\bar F(0, x) = F(0, h^{-1}(x)) = \mathrm{id}(h^{-1}(x)) = h^{-1}(x)
$$
and
$$
\bar F(1, x) = F(1, h^{-1}(x)) = h(h^{-1}(x)) = x.
$$

Comment: Oh! I can’t believe that it is so simple! Thank you very much!